# Como crear Directiva con angularjs

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, drag-and-drop, angularjs-scope

Estoy probando interact.js v1.2.9 la cual sirve para drag and drop. quiero crear una directiva de AngularJS v1.6.4 para comunicarme con mi controlador y modificar el scope, cuando llevo mi codigo a la practica los objetos que estoy creando tienen problemas con las coordenadas y con el comportamiento en general.

```
// directives.directive('draggable', ['$rootScope', '$document', 
'interactJS', 'uuid', function($rootScope, $scope, $document, interactJS, 
uuid) {

//     return {
//         scope: {
//             onDrop: '&'
//         },
//         controller: ["$scope", function($scope, element, attr, controller) {
//             console.log($scope, element, attr, controller);
//             // $scope.tituloLista = $scope.opciones[0].tipos;
//             // $scope.seleccion = {};
//             // angular.forEach($scope.ngModel, function(id) {
//             //     $scope.seleccion[id] = true;
//             // });
//         }],

//         link: function(scope, element, attr, controller) {
//             // var test = interactJS.test('scope, window.interact');
//             console.log(interactJS);
//             console.log(uuid.new());
//         }
//     //     link: (function(scope, element, attr, controller) {
//     //     var transformProp;
//     //     console.log(scope, element, attr, controller);
//     //     interact.maxInteractions(Infinity);

//     //     el = interact('.js-drag');
//     //     el.draggable({
//     //             max: Infinity,
//     //             maxPerElement: 2,
//     //         })
//     //     .on('dragstart', function(event) {
//     //         event.interaction.x = parseInt(event.target.getAttribute('data-x'), 10) || 0;
//     //         event.interaction.y = parseInt(event.target.getAttribute('data-y'), 10) || 0;
//     //     })
//     //     .on('dragmove', function (event) {
//     //         // console.log(event);
//     //         event.interaction.x += event.dx;
//     //         event.interaction.y += event.dy;

//     //         if (transformProp) {
//     //             event.target.style[transformProp] =
//     //                 'translate(' + event.interaction.x + 'px, ' + event.interaction.y + 'px)';
//     //         } else {
//     //             event.target.style.left = event.interaction.x + 'px';
//     //             event.target.style.top  = event.interaction.y + 'px';
//     //         }
//     //     })
//     //     .on('dragend', function (event) {
//     //         event.target.setAttribute('data-x', event.interaction.x);
//     //         event.target.setAttribute('data-y', event.interaction.y);
//     //     });

//     //     // setupDropzone('.js-drop', '#drag1, #drag2, #drag3, #drag4');
//     //     setupDropzone('.js-drop', '#drag1, #drag2, #drag3, #drag4');


//     //     /**
//     //      * Setup a given element as a dropzone.
//     //      *
//     //      * @param {HTMLElement|String} el
//     //      * @param {String} accept
//     //      */
//     //     function setupDropzone(el, accept) {
//     //         interact(el)
//     //             .dropzone({
//     //                 //accept: accept,
//     //                 ondropactivate: function (event) {
//     //                     addClass(event.relatedTarget, '-drop-possible');
//     //                 },
//     //                 ondropdeactivate: function (event) {
//     //                     removeClass(event.relatedTarget, '-drop-possible');
//     //                 }
//     //             })
//     //             .on('dropactivate', function (event) {
//     //                 var active = event.target.getAttribute('active')|0;

//     //                 // change style if it was previously not active
//     //                 if (active === 0) {
//     //                     addClass(event.target, '-drop-possible');
//     //                     event.target.textContent = 'Drop me here!';
//     //                 }

//     //                 event.target.setAttribute('active', active + 1);
//     //             })
//     //             .on('dropdeactivate', function (event) {
//     //                 var active = event.target.getAttribute('active')|0;

//     //                 // change style if it was previously active
//     //                 // but will no longer be active
//     //                 if (active === 1) {
//     //                     removeClass(event.target, '-drop-possible');
//     //                     event.target.textContent = 'Dropzone';

//     //                 }

//     //                 event.target.setAttribute('active', active - 1);
//     //             })
//     //             .on('dragenter', function (event) {
//     //                 addClass(event.target, '-drop-over');
//     //                 event.relatedTarget.textContent = 'I\'m in';
//     //             })
//     //             .on('dragleave', function (event) {
//     //                 removeClass(event.target, '-drop-over');
//     //                 event.relatedTarget.textContent = 'Drag me…';
//     //                 //scope.onDrop({dragEl: event.relatedTarget.id, dropped: false});
//     //             })
//     //             .on('drop', function (event) {
//     //                 removeClass(event.target, '-drop-over');
//     //                 console.log(event.relatedTarget.id);
//     //                 event.relatedTarget.textContent = 'Dropped';
//     //                 console.log(scope, element, attr, controller);
//     //                 //scope.onDrop({dragEl: event.relatedTarget.id, dropped: true});
//     //             });
//     //     }

//     //     function addClass (element, className) {
//     //         if (element.classList) {
//     //             return element.classList.add(className);
//     //         }
//     //         else {
//     //             element.className += ' ' + className;
//     //         }
//     //     }

//     //     function removeClass (element, className) {
//     //         if (element.classList) {
//     //             return element.classList.remove(className);
//     //         }
//     //         else {
//     //             element.className = element.className.replace(new RegExp(className + ' *', 'g'), '');
//     //         }
//     //     }

//     //     interact(document).on('ready', function () {
//     //         transformProp = 'transform' in document.body.style
//     //             ? 'transform': 'webkitTransform' in document.body.style
//     //             ? 'webkitTransform': 'mozTransform' in document.body.style
//     //             ? 'mozTransform': 'oTransform' in document.body.style
//     //             ? 'oTransform': 'msTransform' in document.body.style
//     //             ? 'msTransform': null;
//     //     });

//     // }(window.interact))
//     };
// }]);
```

si hago la directiva de esa forma funciona bien pero no me puedo comunicar con el scope.

```
link: (function(scope, element, attr, controller) {
```

esa linea de código altera el funcionamiento de angular

```
link: function(scope, element, attr, controller) {
```

asi funciona el scope pero no renderiza bien el objeto dragandrop

El codigo original que quiero transformar en directiva es:

HTML: 
https://github.com/taye/interact.js/blob/stable/demo/dropzones.html

JS: 
https://github.com/taye/interact.js/blob/stable/demo/js/dropzones.js

Mi duda surge en como tengo que transformar el JS para crear una o varias directivas de angular

Comment: puedes poner un ejemplo funcional porfavor!!!,

Comment: buen dia, basicamente lo que quiero es convertir https://github.com/taye/interact.js/blob/stable/demo/js/dropzones.js en una directiva